# covert pandas dataframe to dict in python3 is not coming as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

would like to get some suggestions to find what i am doing wrong.
i have some url data,and i have extracted the query parameters(more than one param). after that i am trying to convert to dict, but the dict is coming properly.

input:

```
0,adid=,targetid=kwd-80676938665090:loc-188,msclkid=18674723de8319b2a2272410d0077f2f,utm_source=bing,utm_medium=cpc
```

output:

```
{0: ',adid=,targetid=kwd-80676938665090:loc-188,msclkid=18674723de8319b2a2272410d0077f2f,utm_source=bing,utm_medium=cpc'}
```

but the expected output should be,

```
{'adid':,'targetid':'kwd-80676938665090:loc-188','msclkid':'18674723de8319b2a2272410d0077f2f','utm_source':'bing','utm_medium':'cpc'}
```

code tried:

```
import urllib.parse
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs
import pandas as pd

name_of_file =  "weburluservisited.xlsx"
data = pd.read_excel(name_of_file)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1["path"] = df1["RequestedURL"].apply(lambda path: 
urllib.parse.urlparse(path).path)
df1["params"] = df1["RequestedURL"].apply(lambda params: 
urllib.parse.urlparse(params).params)
df1["query"] = df1["RequestedURL"].apply(lambda query: 
urllib.parse.urlparse(query).query)

df1['qp'] = df1['query'].str.split('&').str.join(',')
df1['qp1'] = df1['qp'].str.split('=').str.join(':')
df1['qp2'] = df1['qp1'].str.replace(' ','', regex=True)
print(df1['qp2'].to_dict())
```

input url: https://www.goh.com/?&adid=&targetid=kwd-80676938665090:loc-188&msclkid=18674723de8319b2a2272410d0077f2f&utm_source=bing&utm_medium=cpc

Comment: Please share the code you used to get your current output.

Comment: What does this have to do with pandas? You've asked "would like to get some suggestions to find what i am doing wrong." but haven't shared what you have done.

Comment: The query string in your example isn't a valid HTTP query string. It needs`&` between the values, not `,`. You are also importing `parse_qs` without using it. The `0` prefix is also weird and probably needs slicing off.

Comment: Thank you Mat. i am doing the split to finding & by using following line of code df1['qp'] = df1['query'].str.split('&').str.join(',')
df1['qp1'] = df1['qp'].str.split('=').str.join(':'). i have updated the actual url in the main question. actually i need to get the path, get the query param in a dataframe for each sessionid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using Pandas, you could do the following...

```
>>> qs = "0,adid=,targetid=kwd-80676938665090:loc-188,msclkid=18674723de8319b2a2272410d0077f2f,utm_source=bing,utm_medium=cpc"

>>> output = dict([i.split("=") for i in qs.split(",") if "=" in i])
>>> print(output)
{'adid': '', 'targetid': 'kwd-80676938665090:loc-188', 'msclkid': '18674723de8319b2a2272410d0077f2f', 'utm_source': 'bing', 'utm_medium': 'cpc'}
```

Comment: Thank you Mat, i have more than one record and i want add back to the original dataframe for further analysis. original data frame contains columns like sessionid, original ur, and want to add the new parsed query parameter as a column

Comment: Are you able to provide a sample of `weburluservisited.xlsx`?

Comment: Thank you Mat finally i were able to get it.